# list of dictionary: aggregate value by grouping by inner dictionary key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, aggregate

**I have this signature:**

```
def aggregate_by_player_id(input, playerid, fields):
```

By 'fields', i mean fields to sum up grouping by 'playerID' within the 'input'.

**I call the function like this:**

```
aggregate_by_player_id(input, 'player', ['stat1','stat3'])
```

**Input look like this:**

```
[{'player': '1', 'stat1': '3', 'stat2': '4', 'stat3': '5'},
{'player': '1', 'stat1': '1', 'stat2': '4', 'stat3': '1'},
{'player': '2', 'stat1': '1', 'stat2': '2', 'stat3': '3'},
{'player': '2', 'stat1': '1', 'stat2': '2', 'stat3': '1'},
{'player': '3', 'stat1': '4', 'stat2': '1', 'stat3': '6'}]
```

**My output structure is:**

```
nested_dic = {value_of_playerid1: {'playerid': value_of_playerid1, 'stat1': value_of_stat1, 'stat2': value_of_stat2}, 
              value_of_playerid2: {'playerid': value_of_playerid2, 'stat2': value_of_stat2, 'stat2': value_of_stat2}, 
              value_of_playerid3: {'playerid': value_of_playerid3, 'stat3': value_of_stat3, 'stat3': value_of_stat3}}
```

**Hence the output should look like:**

```
{'1': {'player': '1', 'stat1': 4, 'stat3': 6}, 
 '2': {'player': '2', 'stat1': 2, 'stat3': 4}, 
 '3': {'player': '3', 'stat1': 4, 'stat3': 6}}
```

Comment: It looks like you're looking to *sum* the attributes of dictionaries (`'stat1','stat3'`) for all entries that have matches values for some other attribute (`'player'`)? Have you looked at dictionary comprehensions and tried anything yourself?

Comment: hello. i try to sum up ('stat1','stat3') per playerID. i tried a lot of for loops. I end up summing all the players or retianing only the last one...

Comment: If you have pandas this is actually pretty simple.

Comment: i dont know pandas but i can learn... i am a beginner in python but i do my best

Comment: Ah, nvm then. I don't recommend breaking open an entirely new library just for one specific task. It's meant for data reshaping, transformation and aggregation, so you may want to keep its existence in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this to group on `playerid` and then sum values across the fields.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def aggregate_by_player_id(input_, playerid, fields):
    player = itemgetter(playerid)
    output = {}

    for k, v in groupby(input_, key=player):
        data = list(v)
        stats = {playerid: k}

        for field in fields:
            stats[field] = sum(int(d.get(field, 0)) for d in data)
        output[k] = stats
    return output

data.sort(key=player) # data must be pre-sorted on grouping key
results = aggregate_by_player_id(data, 'player', ['stat1', 'stat3'])

{'1': {'player': '1', 'stat1': 4, 'stat3': 6},
 '2': {'player': '2', 'stat1': 2, 'stat3': 4},
 '3': {'player': '3', 'stat1': 4, 'stat3': 6}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Capturing the result you're after in a single comprehension might be possible, but is likely not very readable. Here's a simple function that does the work:

```
data = [
    {'player': '1', 'stat1': '3', 'stat2': '4', 'stat3': '5'},
    {'player': '1', 'stat1': '1', 'stat2': '4', 'stat3': '1'},
    {'player': '2', 'stat1': '1', 'stat2': '2', 'stat3': '3'},
    {'player': '2', 'stat1': '1', 'stat2': '2', 'stat3': '1'},
    {'player': '3', 'stat1': '4', 'stat2': '1', 'stat3': '6'}
]


def aggregate_dicts(ds, id_field, aggr_fields):
    result = {}
    for d in ds:
        identifier = d[id_field]
        if identifier not in result:
            result[identifier] = {f: 0 for f in aggr_fields}
        for f in aggr_fields:
            result[identifier][f] += int(d[f])
    return result


print(aggregate_dicts(data, 'player', ['stat1', 'stat3']))
```

Result:

```
{'1': {'stat1': 4, 'stat3': 6}, '2': {'stat1': 2, 'stat3': 4}, '3': {'stat1': 4, 'stat3': 6}}
```

If you want to repeat the identifier inside the dict, just add this line to the `if` block:

```
            result[identifier][id_field] = identifier
```